# Can someone explain this JavaScript syntax? const { variable } = require(

Tags: javascript, node.js, syntax

I don't have much experience with javascript and I have been looking for an explanation into this syntax so if you know it would be much appreciated if you can help me understand it!

**In Node.js**

```
const { check, validationResult }   = require('express-validator/check');
const { matchedData, sanitize }     = require('express-validator/filter');
```

I am used to declaring variables like this:

```
const name = require('npm-module..');
```

Could someone explain this to me?

Comment: it is called a destructuring assignment, you can read more about it here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment

Comment: It's a destructuring assignment, imagine this, you have an object, that has another object with some properties that you want to get

    `const myObject = {
     coolProp: {
       age: 2000,
        name: 'super cool'
     }
    }`

instead of doing it like this

    `const age = myObject.coolProp.age`
    `const name = myObject.coolProp.name`

you could achieve the same with

    `const {age, name} = myObject.coolProp`

and it would get those properties from it and give them your new variables the same name

Comment: wanted to provide it as an answer but these editing guys are always ruining it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is called destructuring assignment.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment

You are basically telling JS that require statement will return an object, and if it can pull out for you the property

`check` and `validationResult` in 2 const with the same name.

The syntax can go deeper with assigning default values or pulling out nested objects.